# Way to use anchors/references in job.<spec>.script for DRYness

Tags: dry, gitlab-ci

I'm fairly new to using `gitlab-ci` and as such, I've run into a problem where the following fails `ci-lint` because of my use of anchors/references:

---

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375

.install_thing1: &install_thing1
  - do things
  - to install
  - thing1

.install_thing2: &install_thing2
  - do things to
  - install thing2

.setup_thing1: &setup_things1
  variables:
    VAR: var
    FOO: bar
  script:
    - all
    - the
    - things

before_script:
...

stages:
  - deploy-test
  - deploy-stage
  - deploy-prod

test:
  stage: deploy-test
  variables:
    RUN_ENV: "test"
...
  only:
    - tags
    - branches
  script:
    - *install_thing1
    - *install_thing2
    - *setup_thing1
    - other stuff
...

test:
  stage: deploy-stage
  variables:
    RUN_ENV: "stage"
...
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - *install_thing1
    - *install_thing2
    - *setup_thing1
    - other stuff
```

When I attempt to lint the `gitlab-ci.yml`, I get the following error:

```
Status: syntax is incorrect 
Error: jobs:test:script config should be a string or an array of strings
```

The error eludes to just needing an array for the `script` piece, which I believe I have. Use of the `<<: *anchor` pragma causes an error as well.

So, how can one accomplish what I'm trying to do here where I don't have to repeat the code in every -block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it and even make it more DRY, take a look at [the Auto DevOps template Gitlab created](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/vendor/gitlab-ci-yml/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml).

It can fix your issue and even more improve your CI file, just have a template job like their [`auto_devops` job](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/vendor/gitlab-ci-yml/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml#L215), include it in a [before_script](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/vendor/gitlab-ci-yml/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml#L433) and then you can combine and call [multiple functions](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/vendor/gitlab-ci-yml/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml#L196) in a script block.

The anchors only give you limited flexibility.

(This concept made it possible for me to have one CI file for 20+ projects and a centralized functions file I `wget` and load in my `before_script`.)

Comment: awesome! This should help immensely! Thanks!

Comment: Np; I documented more detailed examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790403/share-gitlab-ci-yml-between-projects/47976087#47976087

Comment: Links are broken.