# GitLab CI/CD Generic configuration

Tags: yaml, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I have to setup almost the same pipeline for 30+ repositories in gitlab. The problem is that I can not find any possibility in gitlab that will let me to setup one pipeline using YAML and reuse it in all other repos with providing additional params.

As a sample, if I do it via Jenkins it is pretty straightforward, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use anything apart from gitlab ci/cd.

Any ideas about generic pipelines in GitLab?

Comment: Well, you may check the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790403/share-gitlab-ci-yml-between-projects

Comment: thanks for the url, it is partaly helpful, as well I find out one more thing form here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include I think I'm going to try that solution as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered causing each of your project pipelines to trigger a child pipeline? The child pipeline can be defined in a file in another project than the pipeline which triggers it. There are some details on parent-child pipelines here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html