# Is there anything similar to Jenkins shared libraries in gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, shared-libraries, pipeline

I want to know if we have something similar to Jenkins shared libraries in gitlab. I have some shell scripts that I want to make it accessible to all applications in gitlab. Shared libraries in Jenkins provided a way for that without requiring applications to do much on their side and also was easy to maintain and make changes.
Is there something similar in gitlab too?

Comment: Possibly dynamic child pipelines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094780/6309